# differences in .Net SerialPort C# running on 32 bits Windows 7 and 64 bits Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, serial-port

is there any differences in .Net SerialPort C# running on 32 bits Windows 7 and 64 bits Windows 10?

I have a serial communicator library that we build on top of .net 4.5, for some reason, when we run them on windows 7 and below, it works fine. But we always end up with serial device hanged if we run them on windows 10 64 bits.

This happened when we attempt to transfer kbs of files to the device. We have tried with Thread.sleep in between each write and even reduce the size transfer each time, but the issue still persists.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet is to run the program in compatibility mode on the Windows 10 machine.  There should be an option for Windows 7.

Comment: @Baddack does usb-serial adapter matters? I was told my team attempted to run them on windows 10 embedded version

Comment: Yes, you will need drivers for the USB-Serial Adapter depending on the Operating System.  You'll have to get the Windows 10 version from your vendor.  We use the CP210X drivers from Silicon Labs and we have to install the appropriate OS version.